# AngularJS - Checkbox not reflecting value from back-end

Tags: angularjs

Have a checkbox which should show yes when true and no when false. Unfortunately, while it does work and it does allow you to change the back-end value when you click it. It constantly shows the value to be false. Any help?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="useAppEntitlements"
        class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 control-label no-padding-right">Use
    Application
    Entitlements?</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
        <label class="margin-top-5">
            <input name="useAppEntitlements" id="useAppEntitlements"
                class="checkbox-slider yesno"
                type="checkbox"
                ng-model="targetEntity.useAppEntitlements"
                ng-true-value="1"
                ng-false-value="0"
                ng-disabled="editMode == false && !isNewSite">
            <span class="text"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering where exactly the issue might stem from if it's not showing the correct value when the back-end JSON shows it to be true?

Comment: What's in the `targetEntity` object ?

Comment: When it's coming from the back-end, is `targetEntity.useAppEntitlements` equal to `1` or `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this simple plunk I created:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/TEj3nJLNPIWp77lW?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

You create a $scope.targetEntity object like so:

```
$scope.targetEntity = {
 useAppEntitlements = false;
}
```

As you can by the console log, every time you click the checkbox it alternates between true and false(0 and 1).